Are ultraconnected spaces divisible?
A space is divisible (aka strongly connectionwise normal) if for every neighborhood $D$ of its diagonal, there is a second neighborhood $E$ such that $E\circ E\subseteq D$.
Every hereditarily connected space is divisible, since the only neighborhood of the diagonal is the entire square. Similarly, a space with a focal point (a point which has a unique neighborhood, the entire space) is divisible for the same reason.
Both such spaces are ultraconnected: every pair of nonempty closed sets intersects. Is it true that the only neighborhood of the diagonal in a ultraconnected space is the entire square? If not, are ultraconnected spaces divisible for some other reason?

They are, in fact, divisible, for exactly the reason you suspected - any neighborhood $D$ of the diagonal in $X \times X$ is already the entire space $X \times X$, assuming $X$ is ultraconnected.
Indeed, let $x, y \in X$. Since $X$ is ultraconnected, there is a point $z \in \overline{\{x\}} \cap \overline{\{y\}}$. Since $(z, z) \in D$ and $D$ is open, there are open neighborhoods $U, V$ of $z$ in $X$ s.t. $U \times V \subset D$. But $z \in \overline{\{x\}}$ and $U$ is an open neighborhood of $z$, so we have $x \in U$. Similarly, $y \in V$. Thus, $(x, y) \in U \times V \subset D$. As $x, y$ are arbitrary, this shows $D = X \times X$.

And in fact, a unique neighborhood for the diagonal is a characterization of ultraconnected spaces.
Suppose we have two nonempty closed sets $H,L$ with empty intersection. Then $H\times L$ is a non-empty closed subset of the square missing its diagonal, so its complement is a neighborhood of the diagonal distinct from the square.
